# Sum and product of greatest prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Consider this functions below.

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}gpf(k)$$ $$g(n)=\prod_{2}^{n}gpf(k)$$

where $gpf$ is the greatest prime factor function.(For example, $gpf(30)=5$)

Is it possible to find an asymptotic formula for $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ for larger $n$?

Or lets simplify the question. Assume $p\leq n$ is a prime number. For how many $m\leq n$, $gpf(m)=p$ is true?

Comment: Your functions are OEIS sequences [A088822](https://oeis.org/A088822) and [A104350](https://oeis.org/A104350).  The asymptotics of $f(n)$ are listed in A088822, but the asymptotics of $g(n)$ are not listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asymptotics of $f(n)$ is given by
$$
f(n)\sim \frac{\zeta(2)}{2}\frac{n^2}{\log(n)}.
$$
More generally, 
let $b_m(n)$ be the $m$-th power of the greatest prime factor in the prime factorization of $n$. Then Jakimczuk proved in [this paper](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijcms/ijcms-2013/9-12-2013/jakimczukIJCMS9-12-2013-2.pdf) that
$$
\sum_{k=2}^nb_m(k)\sim \frac{\zeta(m+1)}{m+1}\frac{n^{m+1}}{\log(n)}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

I can give you some bounds for $g$.  We have $g(x) \ge \prod_{p^k \le x} p = \exp(\psi(x))$ where $\psi(x)$ is the [second Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function).
This has known asymptotics 
$ \psi(x) = x + O(x/\log x)$, so $g(x) \ge \exp(x + O(x/\log x))$.

On the other side, there's the obvious $gpf(n) \le n$, which leads to 
$g(x) \le x! < \exp(x \log x)$.

Numerically, it looks to me like $\log(g(x))/(x \log x)$ approaches a constant near $0.6$ as $x \to \infty$.  Here's a plot:

[image]